# Multilingual typesetting with polyglossia results in Inverted Parentheses using algorithmic+algpsuedocode

Tags: xetex, algorithms, hebrew

I am attempting to compile an article using the XeTex engine. In my document I've used the `algorithmic` and `algpsuedocode` packages in order to describe an algorithm.

Also, the document is meant to contain both Hebrew and English therefore, I've used the polyglossia package and because the algorithm is in english I've put it inside `\begin{english}` environment as per polyglossia's documentation. The output contains inverted parentheses in the function's name.

Here is the complete document

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily{\englishfont}{Latin Modern Roman}
\newfontfamily{\hebrewfont}[Script=Hebrew]{David CLM}
\newfontfamily{\hebrewfontsf}[Script=Hebrew]{Miriam CLM}
\newfontfamily{\hebrewfonttt}[Script=Hebrew]{Miriam Mono CLM}

\begin{document}
\section{אלגוריתם לדוגמה}

\begin{english}
\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{Euclid’s algorithm}
    \label{euclid}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1] % The number tells where the line numbering should start
        \Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$} \Comment{The g.c.d. of a and b}
            \State $r\gets a \bmod b$
            \While{$r\not=0$} \Comment{We have the answer if r is 0}
                \State $a \gets b$
                \State $b \gets r$
                \State $r \gets a \bmod b$
            \EndWhile\label{euclidendwhile}
            \State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The gcd is b}
        \EndProcedure
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{english}
\end{document}
```

However as you can see in the output the parentheses are not in the right order.
[image: Algorithm Output Screenshot]

I don't know much about the internals, however in the file `algpsuedocode.sty` I can see the following:

```
\algdef{SE}[FUNCTION]{Function}{EndFunction}%
   [2]{\algorithmicfunction\ \textproc{#1}\ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{}{(#2)}}%
   {\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicfunction}%
```

Could this be the root of the problem?

Comment: Does the problem persist if you use another font? I don't have the `David` font and can't reproduce the problem with e.g. Arial  https://i.stack.imgur.com/acqrH.png

Comment: You are correct, changing the font to Arial does work, however in case I would have wanted to use David is there any other solution? From my testing, in case I change the document's main language to English and the other language to Hebrew it is sovled, maybe this indicates that the `\begin{english}` environment doesn't take care of everything?

Comment: Can you try to narrow down your example? For example do you actually need an algorithm or does the same happen in `(test)` as well?

Comment: It is working as expected. Only flips inside the algorithm environment as part of the function signature. Even inside the algorithm environment but somewhere else it doesn't invert the direction

Comment: I think I figured it out.. see here: https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/598#issuecomment-1575318510

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem, even with `David CLM`

Comment: Can you check in .log file if there are any warnings about a font not containing the Hebrew script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a bug in `polyglossia` that has been fixed in version 1.61 (2023/04/16).

Overleaf has an older version apparently. You can work around the issue by adding to your document preamble:

```tex
    \makeatletter
    \providecommand*\xpg@set@group@aux{}
    \providecommand*\xpg@unset@group@aux{}
    \renewenvironment{otherlanguage}[2][]
    {
        \xpg@set@group@aux%
        \selectlanguage[#1]{#2}%
        \xpg@set@normalfont{#2}%
    }
    {\xpg@unset@group@aux}
    \makeatother
```

Edit: provide `\xpg@set@group@aux{}` and `\xpg@unset@group@aux{}` as these are not in all versions.